# Can't see buttons at top of webView

Tags: swift

I can't see the buttons that should be on top of the web view that make it go back and forward. I don't know if this is a web view taking up the whole screen problem, or something else. I've tried making a new view with the buttons and putting the view in there. I don't know.

Here is my code:

```
import WebKit
import SwiftUI

struct Webview : UIViewRepresentable {


    let request: URLRequest
    var webview: WKWebView?

    init(web: WKWebView?, req: URLRequest) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        self.request = req
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return webview!
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func goBack(){
        webview?.goBack()
    }

    func goForward(){
        webview?.goForward()
    }
  }



struct ContentView: View {

  @State var searchURL = "https://google.com"

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
        //MARK: BACK BUTTON
        Button(action: {
          Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(searchURL.prefix(4) == "http" ? searchURL : "https://\(searchURL)")")!)).goBack()
        }) {
          Image("arrowshape.turn.up.backward")
        }
        //MARK: FOREWARD BUTTON
        Button(action: {
          Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(searchURL.prefix(4) == "http" ? searchURL : "https://\(searchURL)")")!)).goForward()
        }) {
          Image("arrowshape.turn.up.foreward")
        }
      }
      Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(searchURL.prefix(4) == "http" ? searchURL : "https://\(searchURL)")")!))
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button action should not be a view in itself but should just update a variable that stores the URL to be displayed by the webview. However that is not required.

Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@mdyamin/swiftui-mastering-webview-5790e686833e). Should cover all the scenarios you need without the need to manually manager URLs